# How to compile a go project with multiple packages and files to get an executable file in linux platform?

Tags: go, compilation

For example, I have a project with following structure:

```
hello
    - packageA
        - subDirA
        - Afile1.go
        - Afile2.go
    - packageB
        - Bfile.go 
        - Bfile2.go
    - packageC
        - main.go
        - subdirC
          - xx.json
    - packageD
        -xx.go
```

How can I build them and get an executable file xxx on Linux platform, so that I can directly call them by ./xxxx?

Comment: Why not go build?

Comment: For your convenience: https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started

Comment: @Volker I use `go build hello` , but it throws an error: `no Go file   in xxx/hello`.

Comment: Do go build where your package main resides.

Comment: And do `go build` not `go build whatever`. But best advice is: read the documentation and tutorials and try to understand what packages are, what the main package is and what modules are.

Comment: @Volker  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `go build`

You can run `go help build` to learn more on how to use it. For example, it's possible that you'll want to provide a specific path to `go build`, or build with `./...`. It depends on the exact layout of your project.

I strongly recommend you to read some official Go documentation pages first:

- [Getting started with Go](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started)
- [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code)

Work through the examples in these pages (and the other pages they lead to); this will answer most of your questions. The second link, in particular, talks about properly using `go build` and `go install` to build your projects.